# Including bootstrap in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to include the bootstrap file (external link) in functions.php, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```js
function insert_scripts() {
   wp_deregister_script('stclare1');
   wp_register_script('stclare1', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', false, '3.3.4');
  wp_enqueue_script('stclare1');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_scripts');
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Doesn't work means ... ? Why don't you use plugin instead : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/ ?

Comment: Daft question, you do have this in the correct functions.php of the activated theme?

Comment: Yes, my theme is activated and it's the correct functions.php file.

Comment: @Raptor: I added a bootstrap-button in my backend, but it doesn't appear. This is the button-code: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

Comment: Did you see the CSS loaded in Developer Console, and appear in source code ?

Comment: Yes, it appears in the source code. I tried it also with the wordpress twitter plugin. It works so far, but gyphicons are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to use script in theme, use

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_scripts' );
```

the above(your version) enqueues to admin section

Comment: That's right - I want to add a bootstrap-button in my admin-section - so I used admin_enqueue_scripts instead of wp_enqueue_scripts

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault:

```js
function insert_scripts() {
   wp_deregister_style('stclare1');
   wp_register_style('stclare1', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, '');
  wp_enqueue_style('stclare1');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_scripts');
```

I included the .js file I found on the bootstrap site. Now I replaced the .js file with the .css file and changed the "_script"-part into "_style".